# Google Assistant custom open url command

Tags: httprequest, esp8266, assistant

I made a device on esp8266 microcontroler that is controlled by http. For egzample if i visit on any device in same WiFi site 192.168.4.1/on microcontroler will turn on motor if i visit 192.168.4.1/off microcontroler will turn off motor. I want to control that device by google asistant by saying "Ok google. Turn on motor". Is there any way to create your own google asistant comands that will open website (best in background but not necessary)? Maybe with IFTTT?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer, any luck yet?

Comment: In IFTTT as "if" you can try add google asistant comand and as "then" ad webhooks - webrequest  - url : your url,  method: "get" . Content Type (optional): "text/plain". But unfortunately your url have to be available on internet (not only on your WiFi)